# Can java recognize negative 0 with decimals?

Tags: java

Well it's summer and I'm trying to convert past C program into Java program, and adding more stuff to it. The program is simple it converts number to words and the thing that i added is also converting numbers with decimals into words like 1.01 is "one point one". The problem is when i try to input -0.29 it does not work, but with its positive counterpart (0.29) it does work printing zero point twenty nine.

I've tried creating a condition that if a number is less than -0.009 instead of printing zero point one (0.01) it will print negative zero point one (-0.01) since mathematically -0.01 is lesser than -0.009.

if ((num == 0 || num < -0.009) && x > 0){

```
            if (num == 0){
                    System.out.print("zero point ");
            }

            else if (num < -0.009){
                    System.out.print("negative zero point ");
            }


            if (x > 0 && x < 10){
                var = x / 1;
                System.out.println(conversions[0][var] + "\n");
            }

            else if (x > 9 && x < 20) {
                var = x % 10;
                System.out.println(conversions[1][var] + "\n");
            }

            else if (x > 19 && x < 100) {
                var = x / 10;
                System.out.print(conversions[2][var] + " ");
                var = x % 10;
                System.out.println(conversions[0][var] + "\n");
            }

    }
```

I expect output to be:

Enter number: -0.29

negative zero point twenty nine

But the reality is:

Enter number: -0.29
Enter number:

Comment: x > 0 && in the inner if is unneccessary

Answer (score 1):

Why not take the absolute value of the number, perform your number to string calculation, and then check the sign of the original number? If it's negative, then you can prepend "negative" to the front of the string?